# What do I do wrong when computing this commutator of differential operators?

Tags: operator-theory

I am trying to understand the Lax pair of the KdV equation. I found some [pdf](http://www.pdecomp.net/generalPapers/Lax_Pairs.pdf) (page 5) that gives the Lax pair in the form

$$
L=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-u
$$
and
$$
M=-4\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} + 6u\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 3\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.
$$

Now one needs to compute the commutator

$$[M,L]=ML-LM$$

of the operators above. I tried to compute $LM$ first, but it seems that I made some mistake and I don't understand what I did wrong. Here is my attempt
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left(-4\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}\right) = -4\frac{\partial^5}{\partial x^5}.
$$
By the product rule:
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left(6u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) 
= 6\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right) 
= 6\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + u\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}\right).
$$
Next
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left(3\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) = 3\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}.
$$
and finally
$$
-uM = 4u\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} - 6u^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 3u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.
$$
Now when we add all of those together we get
$$
LM = -4\frac{\partial^5}{\partial x^5}+ 10 u\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} + 12\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \left(6\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-6u^2\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 3\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3} - 3u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.
$$

Apparently the correct result should be
$$
LM=-4\frac{\partial^5}{\partial x^5}+ 10 u\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} + 15\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \left(12\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-6u^2\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 3\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3} - 3u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},
$$
so I am missing
$$
3\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + 6\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$
somehow.

Comment: I think that (one) error is where you write $D^2 3(Du)=3 D^3 u$. I get  $D (Du)=D^2u+(Du) D$ by the chain rule, and then $D^2 (Du)= D^3 u+ 2 (D^2u) D  +(Du) D^2$. There's a second error of the same sort.

Comment: Seconded; don't forget the "field" you eventually act on

Comment: I see I said Chain Rule where I meant Product Rule, sorry. But if the hint has helped you @Joku then you can give an answer yourself.

Comment: Usually when you take the derivative of a derivative, you just get the second derivative, right? Why is it different here?

Comment: @Joku Too long for a comment so I have given an answer to what I think is your underlying question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but indicates where your calculation has gone wrong.

Let us look at the operators $A:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $B:=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$  and calculate the operator $AB$.

Your calculation would yield the answer $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$.

However let's be more careful: what we need to find is the effect that $AB$ would have on every function $\phi(x)$. Recall what $A$ and $B$ mean: $A$ is the differential operator, $B$ is the "multiply by $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$" operator. So we have
$$
AB(\phi(x))
=A(B(\phi(x))
=A(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\phi(x)) 
=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\phi(x)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\phi(x).
$$

That is,
$$
AB=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}.
$$

If you go through your calculations you'll find a few places where you need to make this, or similar, corrections. (For what it's worth, with these corrections, I got the same answer as the paper you reference.)

Comment: Thank you! It is very clear now.